# How to begin a name of XElement with a digit in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

When i write a code ...

```
   var Doc1 = new XDocument(
                            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                            new XComment("XML information ..."),
                            new XElement("24 hours")
                           );
```

it shows me a run-time exception!

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Additional information: Name cannot begin with the '2' character, hexadecimal value 0x32."
```

So what is wrong?
What should I do in order to begin a name of XElement with a digit?
I mean in order to get this result...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <!--XML information ...-->
 <24 hours>
 </24 hours>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot**. The XML rule says that:

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names **cannot start with a number** or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Names cannot contain spaces

For a work around solution  you may add a prefix to your number and it will work:

```
<_24hours>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XML Naming Rules

XML elements must follow these naming rules:

Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
```

You can see more here - http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/